# How to call a method once per ms in Java

Tags: java, timer, 3d

HI.
I want a function in java that automatically called.

for example wen we use `Time` class like blew

the `actionperformerd()` function call every 1second.

```
Timer time = new Time(10,this);
.
.
.
public void actionperformed()
{
        timer.run;
        //i want move a pic every 1millisecond.
}
```

my problem is that `Timer` class only accept int value and it's minimum
value is 1 second and i want call actionperformed every 1 millisecond.

Comment: *"I want a function."* Is not a useful title for a question. The "title" box on the Ask a Question page said (before you started typing in it) "what's your programming question? **Be specific**" (my emphasis).

Comment: so you want to update an object at 1000fps?

Comment: There are in any case no guarantees. Java cannot guarantee there is sufficient capacity to run the job at that time. And though very much can be done in 1 ms it's still limited unless you just start a new thread every time and have a many-core machine.

Comment: as Dan D. pointed out sarcastically, updating every 1ms is unlikely to be useful (and unlikely to succeed).  Computer screen do not refresh that fast: at most you get 150fps or so (please, no uneducated comment *"the human cannot discern more than 24fps"*), so every 5ms should be fine.  **BUT** you then have to be sure that the operation you perform are speedy enough.  You'd probably get better advice from game-programmers than from regular programmers because game programming is an art in itself (been there, done that).

Comment: The screen will only update up to 100 times per second depending on its refresh rate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) accepts milliseconds in parameters. So you can do

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run()  {
  // do stuff
}
}, 1, 1);
```

But to have real-time functionality with milliseconds precision you may need to switch to C.

Comment: Might be easier for the OP if the example did not use an anon. class ?

Comment: Thank you, this worked for moving GObjects in the ACM library.

Answer (score 2):

Try some classes from java.util.concurrent, and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor can do the thing you want to do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something here.
        }
    }, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

BTW, the timer class can't run a job periodically accurately, it can only create one thread to run the task.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate Thread

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    while (!interrupted()) {
      try {
        // move my object, then sleep for a millisecond
        sleep(1);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, in practice, you will rarely manage to have you move function called every 1 ms because other threads are also consuming processor time. So you need to take into account the actual time between the end of the previous thread loop and the current time.

I suggest you read lots of tutorials about "Game Loops", you'll learn how to organise the functions moving objects, rendering, ...

This one is an [interesting article](http://aubykhan.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/android-game-programming-the-game-loop/). Made for Android but can be applied to standard Java.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to be something graphical be aware that you actually update the screen in the EDT (event dispatch thread). The GUI is *not* multithreaded.

By hammering your EDT with updates in 1 ms intervals (even worse if you do this per pic) you might in effect make the GUI unusable - it is busy redrawing is stead of responding to user input.

I really don't know whether that effect occurs 1 ms intervals, but the single threaded design of the GUI is something to take into account.