# A timer in java with accuracy of 0.1 millisecond in 23 milliseconds intervals

Tags: java

I want to execute a function every 23 +-0.1 milliseconds. 
Can this be done in java?
If yes how?
Thanks in advance!

Let's say i want to have HttpGet function with soTimeout 7 ms, can i repeat that in 23 +-1 ms with System.nanoTime()?

Comment: Can you show any code you have tried so far where you did not manage this accuracy? We can help you based on that.

Comment: This might help: https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132960/how-to-call-a-method-once-per-ms-in-java

Comment: 0.1 miliseconds is pretty much accuracy...

Comment: Looks not positive. You might ensure thought that you call 100 times in 2300 ms, a kind of clock based cron.

Comment: Please make the question more readable.

Comment: Let's say i want to have HttpGet function with soTimeout 7 ms, can i repeat that in 23 +-1 ms with System.nanoTime()? Sorry i'm new on this i made the same question comment in the bellow answer...

Comment: Will this "Looks not positive. You might ensure thought that you call 100 times in 2300 ms, a kind of clock based cron." solution give me the accuracy i need in every loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [high resolution timer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129538/high-resolution-timer-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.nanoTime() to take the time and busy wait until the desired time has arrived.  This will be must better than 0.1 milli-second accurate most of the time, but there is a still a small risk that your thread will not be running in which case it cannot perform the action in time.

Comment: Let's say i want to have HttpGet function with soTimeout 7 ms, can i repeat that in 23 +-1 ms with System.nanoTime()?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you try. BTW 7 + 23 is 30, how does 25 ms come into it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, though what i need is that every 23ms , run 7ms httpget and then wait for 16ms sum 23ms and for that 23ms get accuracy of 0.1 ms. Is this going to work and how?

Comment: It will work if you do as I said in my answer.  It is two lines of code.